# Many-to-one relationship in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, many-to-one

I would like to establish a relationship many-to-one between two fields on database. I am using PostgreSQL database and Hibernate. The tables are ApplicationField and Device. The first one has 2 columns: AppFieldId and Name. The second one has NodeId, Description and AppFieldId. The hibernate mapping for ApplicationField is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 05-may-2011 13:21:52 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.cartif.database.ApplicationField" table="APPLICATIONFIELD">
    <id name="iAppFieldId" column="applicationfieldid" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">s_applicationfield</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property column="name" lazy="false" name="name" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <set name="devices">
        <key column="appfieldid" />
        <one-to-many column="nodeid" class="com.cartif.zigbee.device.Device"/>
    </set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And for Device:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                               "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 07-abr-2011 13:29:19 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.cartif.zigbee.device.Device" table="Device">
    <id column="nodeid" name="iIdentifier" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <property column="description" generated="never" lazy="false" name="description" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <set name="appField">
        <key column="nodeid"/>
        <many-to-one column="appfieldid" class="com.cartif.database.ApplicationField"/>
    </set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

On Java classes I have a List devices on ApplicationField class and ApplicationField appField on Device class. However, when I try to create a sessionFactory, I obtain an exception like:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute "column" must be declared for element type "one-to-many".
```

How should I do the relationship between the tables?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the relationship is as follow:

**One ApplicationField has many Devices.

  One Device can refer to Many ApplicationField.**

If It is true, then there are some mistakes in your mapping.

Replace devices set with following (change in Id column):

```
<set name="devices">
        <key column="applicationfieldid" />
        <one-to-many class="com.cartif.zigbee.device.Device"/>
</set>
```

Update many-to-one mapping as:

```
<many-to-one name="appField" column="applicationfieldid" class="com.cartif.database.ApplicationField"/>
```

Comment: The relationship is: One ApplicationField has many Devices.
One Device can refer to ONLY ONE ApplicationField. It's like one contry has several cities but one city is only in one country.

Comment: Okey. Then use unique=true in many-to-one mapping. So, only one device can be attached to only one ApplicationField.